# How to check TRIM status via Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, trim, osx-elcapitan, solid-state-drive

I'm have a Mid 2010 iMac with OWC Mercury Electra 3G SSD.
After the GM seed of El Capitan beta, I started seeing this:
[image]

Through the final release to now, 10.11.1 beta's, issue still exists.  This is fine with me because the SSD drive is functioning properly.  EXCEPT, I enabled trim with final release using terminal:

```
trimforce enable
```

Now, I have no way of checking the status of it (wether it is disabled or not) , since the only way I know is through the system report shown in the screenshot above, and it shows an error.  Is there a terminal command to check the status of trimforce ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Above error from the screenshot is now fixed on the 10.11.2 Beta 1 release.